# Trying to get Selenium to scrape table and click button

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I hacked together the code below to try to scrape data from an HTML table, to a data frame, and then click a button to move to the next page, but it's giving me an error tat says 'invalid selector'.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd


browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Utility/chromedriver.exe")
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

url = 'https://healthdata.gov/dataset/Hospital-Detail-Map/tagw-nk32'
browser.get(url)

for x in range(1, 5950, 13):
    time.sleep(3) # wait page open complete
    
    df = pd.read_html(browser.find_element_by_xpath("socrata-table frozen-columns").get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
    
    submit_button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('pager-button-next')[0]
    submit_button.click()
```

I see the table, but I can't reference it.

[image]

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: I don't think that XPath selector is correct. Wouldn't it be something like `//div[@class='socrata-table frozen-columns']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find button with `find_elements_by_css_selector`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd

browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Utility/chromedriver.exe")
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

url = 'https://healthdata.gov/dataset/Hospital-Detail-Map/tagw-nk32'
browser.get(url)

for x in range(1, 5950, 13):
    time.sleep(3)  # wait page open complete

    df = pd.read_html(
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("socrata-table frozen-columns").get_attribute(
            'outerHTML'))[0]

    submit_button = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('button.pager-button-next')[1]
    submit_button.click()
```

Sometimes pagination hangs, and `submit_button.click()` ends with an error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: 
Message: element click intercepted: 
Element <button class="pager-button-next">...</button> 
is not clickable at point (182, 637). 
Other element would receive the click: <span class="site-name">...</span>
```

So consider to increase timeout. For example, you can use this approach

```
def click_timeout(element, timeout: int = 60):
    for i in range(timeout):
        time.sleep(1)
        try:
            element.click()
        except WebDriverException:
            pass
    element.click()
```

So, you click an element as fast as it will be ready

Comment: I used Paul's recommendation and Eugenij's recommendation, and came up with this.

    df = pd.read_html(
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='socrata-table frozen-columns']").get_attribute(
            'outerHTML'))[0]

    submit_button = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('button.pager-button-next')[1]
    submit_button.click()

However, after running through the loop multiple times, my data frame has a shape of (0, 64), so nothing is being scraped. Thoughts?